# Unwind Segue from popup

Tags: ios, xcode, segue, uivewcontroller

I have UIViewController A, UIVC B, and A has a segue to B. (Using a button)
B has an "OK" button that pops up a window, and once I click "Accept" in the pop up, I want it to return back to UIVC A, or back to be upon "Cancel". Now, the cancel part is easy. How do I implement the returning back to A?

Comment: you give yourself an answer in your title - create an unwind segue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link has a full, awesome explanation about how it needs to be done.

https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2015/12/18/working-with-unwind-segues-programmatically-in-swift/

Answer (score 0):

In viewcontroller A:

```
@IBAction func unwindToViewControllerA(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) { }
```

In ViewController B:

```
@IBAction func dismissClicked(_ sender: Any) {
     performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToViewControllerA", sender: self)
}
```

Make sure you create a named Segue called: `unwindToViewControllerA`, this I does by control - clicking to the EXIT icon (rather than the next view controller when you create a normal segue)

Comment: For some reason it won't let me choose view A when I control-click EXIT on control B. I'll try to fix this asap

Comment: Ok, I know where the problem is. I don't have a button on my UI for the unwind to happen. It's a POPUP window, and I need to PROGRAMATICALLY add the unwind segue there under the "Cancel button clicked" section:

PopupAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .default, handler: {action: UIAlertAction!) in //UNWIND SEGUE HERE)